# Unable to get secret value from AWS secret manager in Dapr component

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, dapr

I am trying to use Dapr with Aws Secret Manager.

I am able to get secrets from aws secret manager through dapr secret API.

But unable to get keys from secret manager when referencing in component.

File: `statestore.yaml`

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: statestore
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: state.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    secretKeyRef:
      name: RedisSecretstore // Name of the secret in secret manager
      key: redis_password //Key in secret 
auth:
  secretStore: awssecretmanager
```

**File**: `secretstore.yaml`

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: awssecretmanager
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: secretstores.aws.secretmanager
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: region
    value: "XXXXX"
  - name: accessKey
    value: "XXXXX"
  - name: secretKey
    value: "XXXXX"
  - name: sessionToken
    value: "XXXXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but after putting lot of efforts. I think, in Dapr there is limitation of multiple key pair per secret with AWS secret manager.

Because when i give secret in plain text it works, but in key/value pair it does not works.